# Is King Lines really/still the best selling climbing movie of all time?

Tags: box-office, king-lines

In the marketing for the movie [*King Lines*](http://senderfilms.com/productions/details/812/King-Lines) they say:

> (2007) The best-selling climbing film of all time. Follow Chris Sharma on his ultimate global quest to redefine the possible in the vertical world.

Clearly movies like [*Cliffhanger*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106582/) aren't included in this statistic. That being said, was that actually true at one time or is that subtly qualified hype aka best-selling for this studio? For it to be anything but hype there would have to be some organization that tracks the sales of all climbing movies from the various producers. If that organization exists would I be able to figure out the best selling skiing, diving,  also from them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basing the results purely on Amazon's bestselling items list (usually a good measure of the overall popularity of a film), you can see that [King Lines](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000XW1NV0) is currently sitting at #105,431 in the "all Movies & TV" category and #3703 in "Sports".

By comparison, the climbing film [Meru](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014JC10KI) sits at #3,577 in the "all Movies & TV" category and #94 in "Sports".

Either the claim is outdated (and should have been retracted long ago) or it's simply marketing hype.